# Detecting and ignoring touch on non-transparent part of MKOverlay drawn Image in iOS8

Tags: ios8, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a overlay image (.png) on my map that consists of a transparent bit in the middle, and colored sides so the user can only focus on the middle part. However do to the shape of that middle bit, quite a bit is visible at some sides.

I'm trying to detect a tap on the OverlayView so I can ignore it and only accept touches in the designated area.

I followed the following tut at Ray Wenderlich's site for adding the overlay:

The image overlay is drawn like this:

```
@implementation PVParkOverlayView

- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay overlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage {
self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];
if (self) {
    _overlayImage = overlayImage;
}

return self;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;

//UIImage *imageTest = _overlayImage;

MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

//orientation testing
//CGContextRotateCTM(context, 0);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);

}
```

I have a gesture recognizer on my mapview and am trying to detect the tap there:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

CGPoint tapPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];

CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:tapPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoord);
CGPoint mapPointAsCGP = CGPointMake(mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y);

for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
    if([overlay isKindOfClass:[PVParkOverlay class]]){

       NSLog(@"overlay is present");

        /*
        MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon*) overlay;

        CGMutablePathRef mpr = CGPathCreateMutable();

        MKMapPoint *polygonPoints = polygon.points;

        for (int p=0; p < polygon.pointCount; p++){
            MKMapPoint mp = polygonPoints[p];
            if (p == 0)
                CGPathMoveToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
            else
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
        }

        if(CGPathContainsPoint(mpr , NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE)){
            // ... found it!
            NSLog(@"I've found it!");
        }

        //CGPathRelease(mpr);
         */  
    }   
}
```

I know that the overlay is there, but since it is a drawn image I can't find a way to convert this to polygon points to use this code (if even possible).

Any other methods I can use for this?

I also found following sample code but the viewForOverlay method is deprecated:

```
- (void)mapTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView *)recognizer.view;
  id<MKOverlay> tappedOverlay = nil;
  for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in mapView.overlays)
  {
    MKOverlayView *view = [mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];
    if (view)
    {
  // Get view frame rect in the mapView's coordinate system
  CGRect viewFrameInMapView = [view.superview convertRect:view.frame toView:mapView];
  // Get touch point in the mapView's coordinate system
  CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:mapView];
  // Check if the touch is within the view bounds
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(viewFrameInMapView, point))
  {
    tappedOverlay = overlay;
    break;
  }
}
}
NSLog(@"Tapped view: %@", [mapView viewForOverlay:tappedOverlay]);
}
```